# Why won't List from Firebase Realtime Database display? Using Ionic and AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I am flummoxed as to why my list will not display.

I am working with the Firebase Realtime Database, and I have no problem at all retrieving and displaying data filed under nodes with the simplest of structures. For example, retrieving data from 
`-|cuisines -|itemId -key:value` works just fine.

In **cuisines.ts** I can throw in a

```
items: Observable<any[]>;
```

with a

```
this.items = database.list('cuisines').valueChanges();
```

in the constructor, and this HTML

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item class="text" *ngFor="let item of items | async">
{{item.name}}
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

everything works just fine. My list of cuisines displays and I'm happy.

If, however, I try to use `*ngFor` to display data that I try to retrieve from the database at this location `-|cuisines -$uid -|itemId -key:value`, the data does not display.

So, in **cuisines.ts**, I have

```
  items: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase, private auth: AngularFireAuth) {
  this.auth.authState.subscribe(user => {
    if(user) this.userId = user.uid
  });
  this.items = database.list(`cuisines/${this.userId}`).valueChanges();
```

I have also tried

```
this.items = database.list('cuisines/' + this.userId).valueChanges();
```

All of this with the same HTML as above. I get no obvious errors. When I `console.log(this.items)`, I get this:

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
operator
:
MapOperator {project: ƒ, thisArg: undefined}
source
:
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: DistinctUntilChangedOperator}
_isScalar
:
false
__proto__
:
Object
```

All my rules are set as openly as possible at the moment, so that's not the problem. It's just that my list does not display. I isolated it down to the database path through a lot of trial and error. When I actually enter a `userId` into the code in the database path instead of `this.userId` my list also displays properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this block:

```
constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase, private auth: AngularFireAuth) {
  this.auth.authState.subscribe(user => {
    if(user) this.userId = user.uid
  });
  this.items = database.list(`cuisines/${this.userId}`).valueChanges();
```

Your `this.auth.authState.subscribe` registers a callback to capture `this.userId`; however, you *immediately* use `this.userId` on the next line, before your subscriber has been called (even if the value is already available, your callback won't get called until the next tick of the event loop).

You need to simply move this line:

```
this.items = database.list(`cuisines/${this.userId}`).valueChanges();
```

Inside the subscribe callback. This means your user will wait a moment to see data, so you might want a loader or an empty message.